# Ember computed properties doesn't work, prototype extensions enabled?

Tags: ember.js

I use the latest ember-latest.js from the GitHub repository.

When I try to use computed properties, it doesnt work. But when I use `Ember.computed` instead of just a function it works.

I think maybe are the prototype extensions disabled. But `Em.EXTEND_PROTOTYPES` is `true`. So why isn't it working?

http://jsfiddle.net/Krutius/TmYuS/

**HTML / Handlebars**

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="test">
    {{test}}
</script>​
```

**Javascript**

```js
App = Em.Application.create({});

Em.View.create({
    templateName: 'test',
    test: function() {
        return("true")
    }
}).append();​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mark a function as a computed property, you have do add `.property()` to your definition, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/zssx4/:

```js
Em.View.create({

    test: function() {
        return true;
    }.property()

}).append();​
```

Have a look at "Computed Properties" in http://emberjs.com/documentation/#toc_ember-js-at-a-glance